# Docbase could not connect to the database error in documentum content server installation

Tags: postgresql, server, documentum, docbase

While I am installing **Documentum content server** on **AWS EKS**, I am receiving this Error.
**Postgress DB** is installed on EC2 VM.

```
14:20:47,013  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerModifyDocbaseDirectory
- The installer will create the folder structure for repository postgres. 14:20:47,021  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerPasswordFileGenerator
- The installer is generating database password file... 14:20:47,111  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerIniGenerator
- The installer will create server.in file for repository postgres. 14:20:47,152  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerCreateTableSpaceScriptGenerator
- The installer will create scripts to for Postgresql Database. 14:20:47,152  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerCreateTableSpaceScriptGenerator
- The URL is jar:file:/tmp/install.dir.208/InstallerData/installer.zip!/dm_CreateTableSpace.sql 14:20:47,209  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerCopyDeleteTableSpaceScript
- The installer will move file /opt/dctm/dba/config/postgres/dm_DeleteTableSpace.sql to a new location /opt/dctm/server_uninstall/delete_db/postgres/dm_DeleteTableSpace.sql. 14:20:47,214  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerCreateTableSpace
- The installer is executing the : Creating the database script. 14:20:47,355  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerWebCacheIniGenerator
- The installer will create webcache.ini file for the repository. 14:20:47,394  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerTestServerIni
- The installer is testing the database connection information 14:20:47,395  INFO [main] com.documentum.install.server.common.services.db.DiServerPostgresqlServer
- The installer is validating the database connection information in the server.ini file. 14:20:47,563 ERROR [main] com.documentum.install.server.installanywhere.actions.DiWAServerTestServerIni
- Docbase could not connect to the database. Please check output file for more information: /tmp/291406.tmp/DBTestResult18051870723865753931.tmp com.documentum.install.shared.common.error.DiException: Docbase could not connect to the database. Please check output file for more information: /tmp/291406.tmp/DBTestResult18051870723865753931.tmp
```

This is log of **dm_CreateTableSpace.out**

```
psql:/opt/dctm/dba/config/postgres/dm_CreateTableSpace.sql:1: ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists
psql:/opt/dctm/dba/config/postgres/dm_CreateTableSpace.sql:3: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: GRANT "postgres" TO "";
                            ^
psql:/opt/dctm/dba/config/postgres/dm_CreateTableSpace.sql:6: ERROR:  database "dm_postgres_docbase" already exists
ALTER DATABASE
GRANT
psql:/opt/dctm/dba/config/postgres/dm_CreateTableSpace.sql:9: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: REVOKE "postgres" FROM "";
                               ^
You are now connected to database "dm_postgres_docbase" as user "postgres".
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
```

I don't understand how to make it working.
Even I am facing issues with Postgres RDS Instant i.e.

```
GRANT "postgres" TO ""
```

The log is getting generated on PostgreSQL ec2 instance

> 2021-07-20 11:53:46.434 UTC [7854] dctm@dm_dctm_docbase FATAL:
> password authentication fail
> ed for user "dctm" 2021-07-20 11:53:46.434 UTC [7854]
> dctm@dm_dctm_docbase DETAIL:  Role "dctm" does not exist.
> Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host    all             all             172
> .16.0.0/16              md5" 2021-07-20 11:53:46.436 UTC [7855]
> dctm@dm_dctm_docbase FATAL:  password authentication fail
> ed for user "dctm" 2021-07-20 11:53:46.436 UTC [7855]
> dctm@dm_dctm_docbase DETAIL:  Role "dctm" does not exist.
> Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host    all             all             172
> .16.0.0/16              md5" 2021-07-20 11:53:49.056 UTC [7857]
> postgres@postgres ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifie
> r at or near """" at character 17 2021-07-20 11:53:49.056 UTC [7857]
> postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  GRANT "dctm" TO ""; 2021-07-20
> 11:53:49.145 UTC [7857] postgres@postgres ERROR:  zero-length
> delimited identifie
> r at or near """" at character 20 2021-07-20 11:53:49.145 UTC [7857]
> postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  REVOKE "dctm" FROM ""; password
> authentication fail                  ed for user "dctm" 2021-07-20
> 11:53:46.434 UTC [7854] dctm@dm_dctm_docbase DETAIL:  Role "dctm" does
> not exist.

I am using PostgreSQL superuser login and is working fine with cli.
updated the value in heml chart i.e values.yaml for documentum : content-server.

Answer (score -1):

Every time you try to re-run the install you should completely delete everything. It looks like Postgres has the tablespace already created and that's why the test is failing

Comment: No, It was not having any tablespace.